# Anyone know what's wrong with this "\maketitle" error?

Tags: titles

[image]

I'm new user of latex, it seems there lacked a "}" but I didn't find where should I insert it

code:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
% The preceding line is only needed to identify funding in the first footnote. If that is unneeded, please comment it out.
\usepackage{ctex}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}
\begin{document}

\title{家具布局组合算法\\
{\footnotesize \textsuperscript{*}Note: Sub-titles are not captured in Xplore and
should not be used}
\thanks{Identify applicable funding agency here. If none, delete this.}
}

\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{1\textsuperscript{st} YunXiang Ma}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{College of Science} \\
\textit{Beijing Forestry University}\\
Beijing China \\
kilokillentak@outlook.com}
\and
\IEEEauthorblockN{2\textsuperscript{nd} Yan Zhuang}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{College of Letters & Science} \\
\textit{University of Wisconsin, Madison}\\
Madison, United States \\
email address or ORCID}
\and
\IEEEauthorblockN{3\textsuperscript{rd} ZhanYi Zhou}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{College of Science} \\
\textit{Beijing Forestry University}\\
Beijing China \\
}
\and
\IEEEauthorblockN{4\textsuperscript{th} YaXuan Liu}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{College of Science} \\
\textit{Beijing Forestry University}\\
Beijing China \\
}
\and
\IEEEauthorblockN{5\textsuperscript{th} HongJun Li*}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{College of Science} \\
\textit{Beijing Forestry University}\\
Beijing China \\
Lihongjun69@bjfu.edu.cn}
}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Comment: don't show a screenshot. Always show a small but complete example that demonstrates the error. Then we can test and debug.

Comment: Sorry but it is not English origin.

Comment: make it shorter. You get an error at the \maketitle command. So everything behind it is not needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\IEEEauthorblockN{2\textsuperscript{nd} Yan Zhuang}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{College of Letters & Science} \\
\textit{University of Wisconsin, Madison}\\
Madison, United States \\
email address or ORCID}
```

should be

```
\IEEEauthorblockN{2\textsuperscript{nd} Yan Zhuang}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{College of Letters \& Science} \\
\textit{University of Wisconsin, Madison}\\
Madison, United States \\
email address or ORCID}
```

You want an ampersand character `\&` and not an alignment point.

Comment: Thanks! It solved my problem.